# Vuetify: How to add aria-labelledby to v-dialog?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to use aria-labelledby attribute on a Vuetify dialog, like this:

```html
<v-dialog v-model="show" max-width="600px" aria-labelledby="testDialogTitle">
  <span id="testDialogTitle">Test Dialog</span>
</v-dialog>
```

But the attribute is not added to the element with role="dialog", it is added to the element which references it from my main template. How can I add this attribute to my dialog with role="dialog"?

Thanks

Comment: What the HTML generated by the `v-dialog` looks like? If there were no other options, you could always add it via javascript by`element.setAttribute('aria-labelledby', 'testdialogTitle')`.

Comment: You can either patch Vuetify source and change the `render` function of VDialog or (as suggested by @tomashauser) you can set the attribute manually by a watcher of `show` - the relevant DOM node should be 2 levels above your `span` (or whatever root element sits inside the default slot of VDialog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hints in the comments, I was able to achieve this by doing:

```html
<v-dialog v-model="show" max-width="600px" ref="dialog" aria-labelledby="testDialogTitle">
  <span id="testDialogTitle">Test Dialog</span>
</v-dialog>
```

```js
watch: {
  show: {
    immediate: true,
    handler: function (newValue) {
      if (newValue) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          const dialog = this.$refs?.dialog;
          const content = dialog?.$refs?.content;
          if (content) {
            // Copy aria-labelledby from v-dialog to new rendered element.
            content.setAttribute('aria-labelledby', dialog.$attrs['aria-labelledby']);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```